# How to enable jmxremote authentication for MobileFirst Platform on Tomcat

Tags: tomcat7, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I try to configure login/password authentication for *jmxremote* connection on Tomcat 7 and MFP 7.1

With the properties `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false` in file  **setenv.sh**, all works fine. I can see the runtimes in the MFP Operational Console

When I change the properties `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate` to true, I don't be able to see the runtime in the MobileFirst Operational Console and I have the following error in the file catalina.out

```
Exception in thread Initialization thread for Worklight runtime prod" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timeout while waiting for the management service to start up.120 secs.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

com.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true means that you activate JMX on Tomcat with client authentication based on a user ID and password, without SSL. In this case other properties are required. See for example https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/index.jsp?re=1&topic=/com.ibm.jazz.repository.web.admin.doc/topics/t_server_mon_tomcat_option2.html&scope=null.

Comment: I already configured that and jconsole tool works fine with authentication but it is not the case of worklightadmin process.